# Zoo full edition upgrade to free with custom app

Tags: upgrade, zoo-cck

I have to upgrade a site from J2.5 to J.3, that has installed the full edition of yootheme zoo component. The site does not make use of the extra apps though, but only a custom app instead.

Anyone knows if the full edition is still needed for the upgrade, or I can simply use the free one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with taking backups.  Since the only difference between full and free are the apps, you don't really need the full version.

Checking the changelog is the key to knowing whether you even need the full version if you're using one of the installed apps.  If no changes are noted to the app portions, you don't necessarily need the full version at upgrade.

What you DO need the full versions subscription for is support and documentation access.  As  much as I've been using Zoo lately and feel at least at an "advanced" level, I find myself using the support forum and documentation regularly.  So having a subscription is important from that standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to migrate from Joomla 2.5 to 3.x whether you have the free or commercial version of Zoo. Both versions support J2.5 and 3.x (they are the same download package) as shown on their downloads page:

http://yootheme.com/zoo/downloads

My suggestion would be to simply take a backup of your site and test the migrations first to see if everything runs smoothly after.